# collect statistics for a single partition in db2 luw

Tags: db2-luw

I have a range partitioned table and I am looking for a way to execute runstat only on the last partition of a the table, because the data is partitioned over time and only the data of the last partitions is changed on each day, is there any any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an ability at the moment.
There is a corresponding "idea" already registered - request for enhancement (RFE) formerly:
[Support of RUNSTATS of range-partitioned tables on single partition](https://ibm-data-and-ai.ideas.aha.io/ideas/DB24LUW-I-651).
It has **Not Under Consideration** status at the moment despite the quite a high number of votes. I believe personally, that it would be very convenient and useful feature as well.
You may vote for this feature as well, if you need it.